# creating an email-defined user in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple web app in django in which users are identified by their email and not a username.
I've been following the guide:
https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username/

**And it works fine!**

Yet, if I choose to have two other required fields the creation of the superuser fails, **while the creation of a normal user does not**.
Can someone help me understand why?

user app - models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user = self.model(first_name=first_name, **extra_fields)
        user = self.model(last_name=last_name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, **extra_fields)


    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email      = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length = 255, unique=False)
    last_name  = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length = 255, unique=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']

    objects = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I tried to understand what was happening for a few hours before posting the question, and naturally I found the answer slightly after posting.

```
user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
user = self.model(first_name=first_name, **extra_fields)
user = self.model(last_name=last_name, **extra_fields)
```

is the trigger for the error in `_create_user()`

the correct code should be:

```
user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, **extra_fields)
```